# Android MediaCodec output format: GLES External Texture (YUV / NV12) to GLES Texture (RGB)

Tags: android, opengl-es, rgb, android-mediacodec, yuv

I am currently trying to develop a video player on Android, but am struggling with color formats.

**Context:** I extract and decode a video through the standard combinaison of *MediaExtractor/MediaCodec*. Because **I need the extracted frames to be available as OpenGLES textures (RGB)**, I setup my decoder (*MediaCodec*) so that it feeds an external GLES texture (*GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES*) through a SurfaceTexture. I know the data output by my HW decoder is in the *NV12* (*YUV420SemiPlanar*) format, and I need to convert it to RGB by rendering it (with a fragment shader doing the conversion).

> MediaCodec ---> GLES External Texture (NV12) **[1]** ---> Rendering ---> GLES Texture (RGB)

**The point where I struggle is**: How do I access the specific Y, U, and V values contained in the GLES External Texture (**[1]**). I have no idea how the GLES texture memory is set, nor how to access it (except for the "texture()" and "texelFetch()" GLSL functions).

- Is there a way to access the data as I would access a simple array (pointer + offset)?
- Did I overthink the whole thing?
- Do either *Surface* or *SurfaceTexture* take care of conversions? (I don't think so)
- Do either *Surface* or *SurfaceTexture* change the memory layout of the data while populating the GLES External Texture (**[1]**) so components can be accessed through GLES texture access functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I would say you're overthinking it. Did you test things and run into an actual issue that you could describe, or is this only theoretical so far?

Even though the raw decoder itself outputs NV12, this detail is hidden when you access it via a `SufaceTexture` - then you get to access it as any RGB texture. Since the physical memory layout of the texture is hidden, you don't really know if it actually is converted all at once before you get it, or if the texture accessors do a on-the-fly conversion each time you sample it. As far as I know, the implementation is free to do it in any of these ways, and the implementation details about how it is done are not observable through the public APIs at all.

Comment: I implemented some tests and you were right. My problem was only theoretical, and running some examples showed me that these troubles were hidden from me. Thanks for the answer